# sylius.repository.product OutOfMemoryException

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

```
"require": { 
    "sylius/sylius": "^1.0@beta",
    "bitbag/cms-plugin": "^1.2",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.3.13",
    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "^6.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.1"
},
```

php Version is : 7.2.0

I've only one product in my Sylius shop

```
class TestController extends Controller {

    public function indexAction($method, $param = array()) {

        return $this->$method($param);
    }

    private function test($param) {

        $repository = $this->container->get('sylius.repository.product');

        // $products = $repository->findOneByCode('simple_produit');
        $products = $repository->findAll(); // Load all the products!

        var_dump($products);

        $content = $this->renderView('JDFTestBundle::test.html.twig');

        return new Response($content);
    }

} /*End of class*/
```

The var_dump show (extract) :

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(Sylius\Component\Core\Model\Product)#19560 (21) { ["variantSelectionMethod":protected]=> string(6) "choice" ["productTaxons":protected]=> object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)#22238 (9) { ["snapshot":"Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection":private]=> [...]
```

Extract picture : 
[image]

How I can get All product without > 1024M data ?! I don't understand what's append.

Thank in advance

Comment: Remove `var_dump` call since it recursively outputs related entity objects (internal ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is causing you to run out of memory is the var_dump call probably.
Try using [dump from the VarDumper component](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/components/var_dumper.html) instead